# Count Duplicates Based on Columns from Multiple Tables Using Multiple Criteria

Tags: sql, mysql

**The Issue**

In my application people can have words tagged on their profile. People can have multiple words on their profile, but each unique word can only be used once per person. I've noticed that some unique words are appearing multiple times eg...

Person A
Tester
Developer
Developer

Person A shouldn't be tagged as 'Developer' twice

To investigate the scope of the issue I need to run a script over the database to see how many people have instances of multiple unique words on their profile.

**The Setup**

We have three tables 'people', 'peopleWords', and 'words', with peopleWords linking the other two tables.
What I have tried is

```
SELECT
    words.wordID,
    words.name,
    COUNT(distinct peopleWords.wordID, peopleWords.peopleID)
FROM
    peopleWords
    LEFT JOIN words ON words.wordID = peopleWords.wordID
    LEFT JOIN people ON people.personID = peopleWords.personID
GROUP BY peopleWords.wordID
HAVING COUNT(peopleWords.wordID) >1;
```

This returns me a count of how many times a unique word is used on a person's profile, but not if the word is used multiple times on a person's profile.

How do I count the number of instances a unique word is used multiple times on a person's account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a result set that shows person, word and how many times that combination appears (above 1):

```
SELECT
    people.personID,
    words.name,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    peopleWords
    LEFT JOIN words ON words.wordID = peopleWords.wordID
    LEFT JOIN people ON people.personID = peopleWords.personID 
GROUP BY peopleWords.personID, peopleWords.wordID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```